# Error 91 "Object not Set" for Tempvar

Tags: vba, ms-access, compiler-errors

I'm new to `Tempvar` objects and keep getting error 91 "Object not Set". I tried setting the `Tempvar` but then error 429 comes up.

I'm using it in a user defined class.

Should the tempvar be "set" or not. Im using it as follows.

```
{ Public tmpSemephore As TempVars 
  tmpSemephore.Add "S" & strParallelKey & "_" & i, 0 }
```

`strParallelKey` is set elsehwere.

Comment: As the error says, the variable should be set. So it's nothing and you don't have anything to add to....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add to TempVars itself, you don't need to create an instance of the TempVars class:

```
TempVars.Add "S" & strParallelKey & "_" & i, 0
```

Gr